# postresql query to check no. of documents is 4

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a master table for applications and another table for documents upload, I want the count of applications which has 4 documents in document table.

master application table=>application_ht_install and
Documents table=>bescom_appl_upload_doc
ack_no is the primary key for application_ht_install and foreign key for application Documents.

And doc_id is for the document id, Help me out guys

```sql
select count(distinct
case when ack_no in 
(select ack_no from bescom_appl_upload_doc) then ack_no end 
) as pending_with_documents
from application_ht_install where service_code in (36) and status_code  in ('ACK','INT')
```

the above query gives count for application with documents, and I want count of application in application_ht_install which has 4 documents in bescom_appl_upload_doc

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Please check again the question, I've provided the sample code

Comment: @krickX check the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way :

```
select count(*)
from application_ht_install A
where
    service_code in (36)
    and status_code in ('ACK', 'INT')
    and (select count(*) from bescom_appl_upload_doc b where a.id  = b.id ) =  4
```

replace `a.id  = b.id` with right connection between tables

well, that would be a new question but I answer it here anyways:

```
select sum(case when docCounter= 4 then 1 end)  countwith4doc
       ,sum(case when docCounter< 4 then 1 end)  countwithlessthan4doc
from (
select a.id, count(*) docCounter
from application_ht_install A
join bescom_appl_upload_doc b 
 on a.id  = b.id 
 and a.service_code in (36)
  and a.status_code in ('ACK', 'INT')
group by a.id
) t
```

Comment: Yes just change =4 to <=4

Comment: Thank you, It worked is this possible to get count for having document with 4 and less than 4 in single query. Like return two column having count of document with 4 and document less than 4

Comment: Thank you so much eshirvana. How can i improve my sql skill? I

Comment: Sorry for asking again for the above problem, Is it possible to get count of applications having all doc_id=(161, 248, 249, 250) and count of application missing any one or more documents, doc_id is a column in bescom_appl_upload_doc . I 've mentioned document = 4 condition earlier. Now count of applications with specific documents

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `having` clause with inner join
Try this:

```
select 
t1.akc_no,
count(*) "count_"
from application_ht_install t1 
inner join bescom_appl_upload_doc t2 on t1.ack_no=t2.ack_no
where t1.service_code in (36) and t1.status_code  in ('ACK','INT')
group by t1.ack_no
having count(*)=4
```

EDIT as per comment:

```
select
count(*) filter (where count_=4),
count(*) filter (where count_<4)
from 
(select 
t1.akc_no,
count(*) "count_"
from application_ht_install t1 
inner join bescom_appl_upload_doc t2 on t1.ack_no=t2.ack_no
where t1.service_code in (36) and t1.status_code  in ('ACK','INT')
group by t1.ack_no
) tab
```

Comment: what is "count_" here is it a variable

Comment: in Subquery "count_" is the column name for `count(*)`. it is not a variable

Comment: Sorry for asking again  for the above problem, Is it possible to get count of applications  having  all doc_id=(161, 248, 249, 250) and count of application missing any one or more documents, doc_id is a column in bescom_appl_upload_doc . I 've mentioned document = 4 condition earlier. Now count of applications with specific documents.

Comment: It is better to open a new question by linking this question because this is totally new question. though I have created a fiddle for your answer [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2b6bb4b271723bf728d209b507b0a746)